# Cassandra read returns AssertionError: "Lower bound [INCL_END_BOUND() ] is bigger than first returned value"

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

My Cassandra server had died and I tried to restore it on the another computer. According this article https://community.datastax.com/questions/4818/backup-and-restore-cassandra-keyspace.html I moved the `data` folder to the new server. All the tables has been restored properly except one of them.
When I try read data from it I get the exception:

```
ERROR [ReadStage-2] 2022-10-19 07:47:55,026 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:166 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-2,10,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: Lower bound [INCL_END_BOUND(2022-10-15 15:23Z) ]is bigger than first returned value [Row: utcdate=2022-10-15 11:07Z | data={t:0.880347,g:0.530729,a:180.0,v:11.7,d:5.896}] for sstable /var/lib/cassandra/data/Telematics_Energo/devicecoordinate-1005f1704edc11ed81fb63e346a603ff/mc-2158-big-Data.db
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorWithLowerBound.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIteratorWithLowerBound.java:127) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorWithLowerBound.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIteratorWithLowerBound.java:48) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.AbstractIterator.hasNext(AbstractIterator.java:47) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.MergeIterator$Candidate.advance(MergeIterator.java:374) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]

< ... cut ... >
```

My query is like this:

```
SELECT 
  utcdate, data 
FROM 
  devicecoordinate 
WHERE 
  id = 00a8efb3-7815-e911-a830-00155d03c802 
  and period = 1663 

  and utcdate >= '2022-10-09 08:55:00+0000' 
  and utcdate <= '2022-10-09 08:56:00+0000' 

order by 
  utcdate
;
```

For others periods the query can execute without exception as well as without `order by` clause.

The table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE devicecoordinate (
    id uuid,
    period int,
    utcdate timestamp,
    data text,
    PRIMARY KEY (( id, period ), utcdate)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY ( utcdate DESC )
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND comment = ''
AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE'
AND caching = {
    'keys' : 'ALL',
    'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE'
}
AND compression = {
    'chunk_length_in_kb' : 64,
    'class' : 'LZ4Compressor',
    'crc_check_chance' : 1.0,
    'enabled' : true
}
AND compaction = {
    'base_time_seconds' : 14400,
    'class' : 'DateTieredCompactionStrategy',
    'enabled' : true,
    'max_sstable_age_days' : 5,
    'max_threshold' : 32,
    'min_threshold' : 4,
    'timestamp_resolution' : 'MICROSECONDS',
    'tombstone_compaction_interval' : 86400,
    'tombstone_threshold' : 0.2,
    'unchecked_tombstone_compaction' : false
};
```

Cassadra version: `3.11.11`

cql_version: `3.4.4`

native_protocol_version: 4

How can I fixed the exception?

Comment: is all the repairs (`nodetool -pr repair`) on each node one at a time completed and insync after the restore operation? Also, if you could update your question with the exact major.minor.patch version of Cassandra, it'd help reviewers to help triage the issue better.

Comment: `nodetool repair -pr Telematics_Energo devicecoordinate` returns 
`Replication factor is 1. No repair is needed for keyspace 'Telematics_Energo'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `AssertionError` is thrown by `UnfilteredRowIteratorWithLowerBound.computeNext()` due to the clustering column value being "larger" than the previous value meaning the clustering rows are out-of-sequence:

```
ERROR [ReadStage-2] 2022-10-19 07:47:55,026 AbstractLocalAwareExecutorService.java:166 - Uncaught exception on thread Thread[ReadStage-2,10,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: Lower bound [INCL_END_BOUND(2022-10-15 15:23Z) ]is bigger than first returned value [Row: utcdate=2022-10-15 11:07Z | data={t:0.880347,g:0.530729,a:180.0,v:11.7,d:5.896}] for sstable /var/lib/cassandra/data/Telematics_Energo/devicecoordinate-1005f1704edc11ed81fb63e346a603ff/mc-2158-big-Data.db
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.rows.UnfilteredRowIteratorWithLowerBound.computeNext(UnfilteredRowIteratorWithLowerBound.java:127) ~[apache-cassandra-3.11.11.jar:3.11.11]
    ...
```

In your case, `2022-10-15 15:23Z` is larger than `utcdate = 2022-10-15 11:07Z`.

The last time I've come across this problem is when a DBA cloned a table to another cluster but didn't create the schema correctly.

In the schema you posted, the clustering order for `utcdate` should be in descending (`DESC`) order:

```
CREATE TABLE devicecoordinate (
    ...
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (utcdate DESC)
```

but there's a good chance the table was created withOUT specifying the clustering order so it defaulted to ascending (`ASC`) order:

```
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (utcdate ASC)
```

When the schema does not match the data in the SSTables, Cassandra will not be able to read the data because the rows are out-of-sequence.

To fix it, you will need to:

1. Drop the table with `DROP TABLE devicecoordinate`.
2. Recreate the table.
3. Restore the SSTables to the new table.

This should fix your problem. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You're right. I have already discovered it.